# How to write a tensor with a bar or a tilde over it?

Tags: math-mode, tensor

I'm trying to write a multi-index tensor with a bar or a tilde over it, usually I use:

```
    \usepackage{tensind}
    \tensordelimiter{?}
    \tensorformat{}
```

but when i write, for example:

```
$?\Tilde{R}_i^{jk}?$
```

the editor returns error. Could someone suggest me how to solve the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Please complete your example such that others can easier copy and test it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensind}

\tensordelimiter{?}
\tensorformat{}

\begin{document}

$?R_i^{jk}?$

$?{\tilde{R}}_i^{jk}?$

\end{document}
```

Note that `\Tilde` is provided by `amsmath`, but it just does the same thing as `\tilde` (it exists for back compatibility).

[image]

You get the same output with `tensor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

$\tensor{R}{_i^{jk}}$

$\tensor{\tilde{R}}{_i^{jk}}$

\end{document}
```